# Stringify an object in YAML

Tags: json, docker-compose, yaml

Is there a way to stringify an object in YAML? I'm looking for something like this:

YAML input:

```
environment: @stringify(
   foo: buz,
   bar: 42,
)
```

Expected JSON output:

```
{"environment": "{\"foo\": \"buz\", \"bar\": 42}"}
```

I *could* of course do this:

```
environment: '{
    "foo": "buz",
    "bar": 42
}'
```

but that has several problems:

1. **No syntax check.** YAML will happily compile, any syntax error inside the JSON will occur "downstream".
2. **No YAML support.** I can't use insertion of objects inside (e.g. `<<: *myObj`).
3. **Extra whitespace.** Newlines in the text can cause problems, especially if the file is written with CLRF endings.
4. **Strict JSON only.** "Extra" JSON features like trailing commas or comments will not be removed, which is extra work "downstream".

Note: I'm using this for `docker-compose`, so if you have a solution specific for `docker-compose`, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) you can see the entire new YAML v1.2.2 specification (released October 1st 2021).
It does specify something called a [JSON schema](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#json-schema), however, this is not what you are looking for.

Once you use YAML's string behavior it is going to be treated as a "normal" string without any specific formation linting (other than the required escaping of characters and so on).

There is no native YAML or docker-compose way to do what you are intending to do.
Since you specified that you are not looking for any scripts or 3rd party programs the answer is:

No, it is not possible.